# Modifying String/Integer object and check if it affects a class object which has the object as its parameter

Tags: java, string, object, assignment-operator

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String name = "john";
    StringTest obj = new StringTest(name);
    name = "peter";
    System.out.println(obj.name);
}
```

}

```
class StringTest{
String name;
StringTest(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Now, since the string name has been reassigned from "john" to "peter" i expect it to print peter but it prints john. Has string being immutable causes a new object to be created when it is reassigned or what is the correct explanation for this?

Also when i try this with Integer object, the behaviour is same! Anyone please explain the reason for this behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java uses *pass-by-value*, which means that you pass the value of `name`, not the reference.
Changing the value of `name` after you already created the `StringTest` instance won't affect your `StringTest` in any way.

Comment: Ya so a copy of the reference to the string name will be passed to the method.. so once i change the string name , it should get reflected in the object which has the reference, right!

Comment: No, when you write `name = "peter";`, you create a new `String` and point the `name` to that `String`. This doesn't affect the class variable `name` in the `StringTest` instance, which will still point to `"john"`.

Comment: okay got it..tq. I Just thought reference would be passed instead of actual string

Comment: @sarish The reference is passed, but when you assign a new string, the variable will contain a **new** reference to that string, the old reference will be unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

I think what throws you off here is the fact that you do not have to use the "new" keyword to create the strings. The code reads more like creating a primitive type like int or long instead of object creation. Which is what is actually taking place.
An equivalent way of creating the two strings is

```
String name = new String(new char[] {'j','o','h','n'});
StringTest obj = new StringTest(name);
name = new String(new char[] {'p','e','t','e','r'});
```

Written that way I think it is more clear why you do not achieve a side effect on the string referenced in StringTest. It has nothing to do with the fact that strings are indeed immutable.